# How to edit htaccess file and index.php file in multiple project in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, base-url

How to edit the `.htaccess` file and the `index.php` file in a multiple project in codeigniter to create a base url in other projects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to read this documentation [Managing your Applications](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html)

Then try this .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /mywebsite

   # Removes access to the system folder by users.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pro1.php?/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pro2.php?/$1 [L]

   # Prevents user access to the application folder
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pro1.php?/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pro2.php?/$1 [L]

   # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
   # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
   # request to index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pro1.php?/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pro2.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have done all the thing that same.

in my application folder i have 
1.Pro1
2.Pro2
and 2 index files in root
1.index.php
2.Pro2.php

Pro2 only run when type Pro2.php in url i want to reomove .php. Pro1 is ok

Answer (score 0):

write individual port htaccess
   port2[
         index.php  //($application_folder = 'application/port2';) //set this     path
          .htaccess//port2
     ]
   port3[
       index.php  //($application_folder = 'application/port3';)//set this path
       .htaccess//port3
     ]

```
application [  
        port1[  
                config[  
                  config.php   
                    -> $config['index_page'] = ''; //set blank  
                  ]    
         ]    
         port2[   
                config[   
                   config.php    
                        -> $config['index_page'] = ''; //set blank  
                  ]  
         ]  
           port3[   
                 config[   
                   config.php   
                        -> $config['index_page'] = ''; //set blank   
                  ]    
          ]   
           ]  

//root directory is port 1 
 index.php // ($application_folder = 'application/port1';)//set this path
```

.htaccess //port1